# What is a Local Kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, machine-learning

I'm reading this [paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/8a20a8621978632d76c43dfd28b67767-Paper.pdf) on Machine Learning explainability, which talks about the [LIME algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04938.pdf) on page 2.

To explain the LIME algorithm, it gives an overview of its objective function:

[image]

In their description of the function, they say that $\pi_{x'}$ is a "local kernel", I've underlined this in red.

If you read the [LIME paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04938.pdf), on page 3, in section 3.2, they say that $\pi_{x'}$ is a proximity measure, which tells you how close a point $z'$ is to the point $x'$.

This makes intuitive sense to me, as $\pi_{x'}$ is used as a weighting for the objective function. But I don't understand how that makes $\pi_{x'}$ a "local kernel".

I understand the kernel of a matrix to be its null space, but that doesn't seem appropriate here. What does a local kernel mean in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you continue reading the [first paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/8a20a8621978632d76c43dfd28b67767-Paper.pdf) you linked, on page 5, they discuss $\pi_{x'}$ again and describe it as a weighting kernel. Keep this in mind.

Next consider the first desirable property that they establish for SHAP-like models:

> The first desirable property is local accuracy. When approximating the original model $f$ for a specific input $x$, local accuracy requires the explanation model to at least match the output of $f$ for the simplified input $x'$ (which corresponds to the original input x).

Remember that $\pi_{x'}$ is fed directly into a loss function $L$, which is given by:

$$ L(f, g, \pi_{x'})$$

where $f$ is your original model, and $g$ is your *"explanation model"*. $L$ calculates the difference between the predictions of $f$ and $g$ and records it as a loss.

This is where $\pi_{x'}$ comes in. $\pi_{x'}$ *is* similar to a matrix's kernel. It's an equation for sample weights that ensures the loss function, $L$, becomes zero when you feed in the sample $x'$.

That's where the term "local kernel" comes from. The equation, $\pi_{x'}$, is local to the sample $x'$, it ensures that the difference at $x'$ is zero, but it doesn't ensure that the difference is zero for every other sample.

For example, if I have two samples $x_1'$ and $x_2'$, and the corresponding kernels $\pi_{x_1'}$, $\pi_{x_2'}$, then $L(f, g, \pi_{x_1'}) = 0$ at $x_1'$, but it is not necessarily equal to zero at $x_2'$.

A general definition could be derived from the [kernel of function](https://www.dhruvonmath.com/2019/04/04/kernels/#:%7E:text=The%20Kernel%20of%20a%20function,its%20inputs%20to%20its%20outputs.), which is the set of inputs that a function sends to $0$. A function's kernel does this for all cases, but a "local kernel" only does this around a specific locality.